# INSERT multiple rows into a MySQL table with Super/Subtypes

Tags: mysql, sql, inheritance

I have the following sub/supertype arrangement in MySQL:
[image]

I also have a CSV of rows that need to go into the rnaseq_voom table, so I want to load the CSV into a temporary table, join it the bmt_gene table, and then batch insert into the supertype `rnaseq`.

However I then need to insert into the subtype, but I can't use `SET @LAST = LAST_INSERT_ID();` because that will just get the last row inserted into the parent table, not the relevant row.

Can I insert into two tables at the same time? How else can you insert multiple rows into a super/subtype relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a set of columns in your data that uniquely identifies a row you inserted, you could do:

```
INSERT INTO rnaseq (columns) SELECT columns FROM temp_table;
INSERT INTO rnaseq_voom (id,more_columns)
    SELECT r.id,more_columns FROM rnaseq r JOIN temp_table t USING (key_columns)
```

Where `columns` is the set of columns to insert into `rnaseq`, `more_columns` those to insert into `rnaseq_voom`, and `key_columns` those that uniquely identify a row of the temp table (to find the the id in `rnaseq` of that row.